# If statement with date comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write an `if` statement that runs some code if the date is after April 24th, 2017, 10 am EDT, but it doesn't appear that my variables are comparable (different data types?).

I'm trying to avoid using Moment.js for just this.

```
var today = new Date();
var launch = 'Mon Apr 24 2017 10:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)';
```

`today` returns `Tue Apr 04 2017 14:34:41 GMT-0400 (EDT)`.

When I test if either is greater than the other, both are false. How should I format my dates?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have to have launch as a date type:

```
var today = new Date();
var launch = 'Mon Apr 24 2017 10:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)';
var launchDate = Date.parse(launch);

if ( launchDate > today )
```

You should also read more about dates here:
[Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: Gotcha. I knew I was missing something like this. Thanks!

Comment: I understand what this does, but for some reason, when I `console.log()` both variables, they both return today's date.

Comment: corrected the syntax.  You have to do a parse because it's a string.

Comment: @MarioParra that is because the console.log is coercing the `today` variable into a string display.

Comment: @Avitus Thanks, but then `launchDate` was formatted in Unix, whereas `today` wasn't, so I used `today = Date.now();` instead.